Maximizing power transfer from 50Hz AC line via toroidal current transformer
This paper looked at ways of achieving high power-to-weight ratio for harvesting power from a 50Hz overhead line.
https://findresearcher.sdu.dk/ws/portalfiles/portal/250674676/EPE_2023_Advanced_Magnetic_Energy_Harvester_for_Charging_Drones_from_Overhead_Powerlines_final_version_.pdf
It clamped a toroidal current transformer to the line and used power electronics to convert to DC for charging.
It used synchronous methods to maximize the power draw taking into account the saturation characteristics of the core.
To me, it seems power-to-weight ratio might also be increased by having an intermediate high voltage DC bus that is stepped down.  The high voltage of the DC bus would allow for a higher power output given the magnetic field / current limitations.  For this setup:

Is it advisable to avoid core saturation?
Would power factor correction on the secondary side significantly increase the throughput, and if so, is it advisable to use AC capacitors with the pickup to create a tank (at 50Hz....), or use an intelligent H-bridge to phase-lock the voltage and current (like this: https://www.ijert.org/research/simulation-of-closed-loop-ac-dc-converter-for-power-quality-improvement-IJERTV4IS031036.pdf)
Is kW range power transfer feasible without degrading the power-to-weight ratio significantly, even if only for a short time (<1min)?
How do I properly calculate the CT equivalent circuit parameters based on the physical parameters (number of turns, wire details, core material, toroid dimensions, air gap length) and model in something like LTSpice?

Some parameters (let's say for a target charging power = 200-300W):

approx 1kg toroidal air-gapped pickup as per above study.
line current ranges from 50 to 200A.
let's say a 600VDC bus so that 1200V semiconductors can be selected.

I am not asking you to design my circuit.  I am not 'being lazy'.  The purpose of this project is not academic / commercial, or even hobby. It can be assumed that the power harvesting is legal. I don't care if this question is 'bad' in some way - I've spent enough time trawling through the net and trying to excavate knowledge from my BE (EEE).  If you would like to help, then please do :)

It is in normal circumstances illegal.  However in this case, no

What makes it legal in this case, out of curiosity? Is it for powering some equipment owned/used by the power company or something?

Essentially, yes.  There's an arrangement regarding this between the government wing using it and the power company.

"Is kW range power transfer feasible..." At a certain point, the weight of a current transformer will exceed the weight of a distribution transformer of similar power connected across the power lines. From calculations I have done previously, I would guess that the break-point would be much below 1 kW. That is, if you need a kW, a distribution transformer will weigh less than a current transformer providing the same power.

At 600VDC bus, for a 1kW output the average current feeding into (and out of) the bus capacitors must be 1.67A.  Is this not achievable with such a 1kg air-gapped toroid CT?

The energy available to the secondary is limited to the primary current times the voltage drop across the primary. The max voltage drop occurs when the secondary is open, i.e. you have a inductor in series with the power line. To get 1 kW from a CT with a 100 A primary requires a voltage drop of 10 V. This requires an inductive reactance of 0.1 Ohm. At 50 Hz, that means 318 uH. But you will need twice that to get your 1 kW power, so 636 uH. So a 636 uH inductor capable of handling 100 A. I'm not sure you can get that with only 1 kg of core, although you can one lighter than a distro xformer.

@MathKeepsMeBusy thanks for the further explanation, but I don't understand how to apply it to my case where I will clamp a line conductor. Does that section of line cable exhibit a voltage drop to provide the power? Think of a clamp ammeter, only delivering serious power

Yes, the clamp causes a voltage drop on the line. Typically, when measuring a current with a CT the voltage drop is negligible. However, when the purpose is to extract power from the line, there MUST be a voltage drop, which is significant if the extracted power is significant.

The even cheekier (read more terrifying) option is to go across the line at 11/12.47kV with a capacitive dropper. You need about 20-25 1.5uF 600VAC capacitors (aiming for 500VAC each) in series to get about a quarter amp. Put a 1-2kV DC bus in series, along with a MOV and bleeder on each cap and a few NTCs to limit inrush. Pack it all in a fibreglass tube a meter long and blow filtered air through it for cooling. Your DC bus controller needs to treat it as a constant-current supply.

@SomeoneSomewhereSupportsMonica - interesting idea, but as I understand, this is grounded?  I need a floating system as it is for a drone.  So similar considerations with capacitive coupling vs weight as with inductive coupling vs weight.

I'm suggesting the drone lands on two wires, not one :) Likely holding a piece of e.g. 40mm PVC or fibreglass tube with the capacitors inside. I was designing for between two phases but if you can get a design capable of contacting one phase and the system neutral (7200V in most of the US) that would work too.

Datasheets don't seem to generally have weights listed. I measured a film cap I have to hand with a density of about 1.3g/cm^3. That would unfortunately put those caps at about 40g each, or ~800G for the set, plus MOVs, NTCs, and packaging. Choosing a smaller number of higher voltage, non-safety-rated, lower capacity parts will improve things, as will manually binning them so you can use 20% tolerance parts.

Minimum line current 50A means we need to drop maximum 20V to deliver 1kW.  I assume we have no way of looping a wire around (power lines are generally solid wire, coated with rigid insulation, and tensioned fairly highly), nor obtaining a loop "in nature", so the primary turns count must be 1.
Voltage should be sine wave to maximize power transfer: downside, this does require a converter stage, which will itself cost some weight.  The next easiest option is the square wave, which can extract more power from a given current, and wouldn't require a conversion stage -- but takes more flux.  This is justified because the peak flux of a square wave is \$\frac{V_{pk}}{4 F}\$, and of a sine, \$\frac{V_{rms}}{\sqrt{2} \pi F}\$, and the power delivered as a sine current and square voltage is \$\frac{2\sqrt{2} V_{pk} I_{rms}}{\pi}\$, and sine/sine, \$V_{rms} I_{rms}\$; thus the power per flux is \$\frac{8\sqrt{2}  I_{rms}F}{\pi}\$ for sine/square and \$\sqrt{2} \pi I_{rms} F\$ for sine/sine.  Reducing common factors, we find \$\pi \gt \frac{8}{\pi}\$ and sine/sine wins.
(Note that excess power into a square wave, can be dumped by simply shorting out the transformer.  A switching converter could also be used, but then the converter could simply be controlled for PFC operation, and you're back to the first case.)
1 kg of steel is ve = 127k mm3, and we can take any proportion of that to make core parameters effective area Ae and magnetic path length le multiply to that quantity.  For GOSS, Bmax = 1.8 T is probably just feasible at this current, so we need
$$ A_e = \frac{V_{rms}}{\sqrt{2} \pi F B_{max} N} $$
or for Vrms = 20 V, F = 50 Hz and Bmax = 1.8 T and N = 1, Ae = 50k mm2.
That's a pretty big core, in general, but notice it only leaves 2.5 mm of length, but we need to somehow curl that enormous cross-section around at least a, oh, 12 mm diameter wire, plus the secondary.  Needless to say, le under 50 mm or so, ain't gonna happen.
A minimum-mass design still needs to account for secondary mass (copper is heavy -- or, do we stretch the core some more to fit larger but lighter aluminum instead?), and there is some back-and-forth to be had on power dissipation and heatsinking: efficiency isn't important, past a certain point anyway, as quite a lot of power can be dissipated into the rapid air streams around the unit; and heatsinking doesn't need to be a pure waste mass, it might be used to carry structural load as well.
Speaking of efficiency, if the props for example are producing huge amounts of tip vorticity, that's a huge waste of power that should be spent purely on lift instead.  Props with winglets, or in shrouds, with director blades, etc. might prove far more successful in extending the range of the unit than sapping some power from a line could.
On a separate note, I wonder how effective the radio is in presence of corona discharge.  The unit will take on most of the potential of the line it's attached to (probably 10s kV), and any projections on the unit will concentrate electric field, leading to corona discharge and RF emissions.  These emissions can extend quite high indeed (100s MHz), and I wonder if it would impair a typical ~GHz band radio.

Thank you for the steer.  Now CHEMMAT courses are coming back to me...  So the power constraint is around the ability of the magnetic material to transfer it.  Will plan accordingly.  When you say "A switching converter could also be used, but then the converter could simply be controlled for PFC operation, and you're back to the first case." - I figure I need to convert to DC anyway, so might as well do it through a transistor H-bridge and do PFC correction.  I assume an architecture similar to the second link I posted would work, unless you otherwise correct me.

Sort of. A synchronous rectifier might smaller as it has almost no switching loss, and no filtering required. Diodes may be smaller, depending on supply voltage and ability to dissipate heat. The transformer (and line, depending on how much emission the power company tolerates for this thing) may suffice for filtering, or more may be required.

Thanks.  A plain diode or synchronous rectifier just flips the negative side of the current waveform resulting in average power factor, right? Does unity power factor increase the throughput, or the core remains the constraint?

PF=1 improves the core area by 19% over square wave (see the ratio above), but this is fairly marginal. There could be other factors to consider in the full design, and making a proper symbolic model of the transformer (wire length, cross-section, dissipation, core volume..), and everything else, would help determine a more completely optimal overall solution.

Oh yeah good spot, I must've fat-fingered 172/50, hah.

Surely the turns count for a straight wire is 0.5 as the wire effectively sweeps 180 degrees (in one side and out the other)?

@Frog What counts is the winding number around the core. Even if current went entirely to infinite distance, the fact that it returns through a loop at all is sufficient to count one. Doesn't matter if the loop is a short loop hooked around the core or a straight wire :)

@Tim Williams yes I see, thanks for clarifying that

Thought I'd better answer my own question.
After reading further, The paper mentioned at the top of the question, re-linked here, represents the state of the art in regard to magnetically extracting power from overhead lines.
The most efficient methods hinge on selecting an optimal transformer core, and then either control the window during which the transformer is shorted, as in the above paper, or manipulate the magnetization via an additional control coil (for example, here).  They all yield about 40-60% improvement over an optimally saturated core, which indicates to me that this is the best that physically can be achieved for a given line frequency.
Answering my own questions specifically:

Is it advisable to avoid core saturation?
No.  The core permeability in the most efficient methods is deliberately overrated to allow for the above manipulations.

Would power factor correction on the secondary side significantly increase the throughput?  No, because we are operating at and beyond saturation.  It is the limiting factor.  However, it is important to control the effective resistance of the charging circuit to maximize power throughput

Is kW range power transfer feasible without degrading the power-to-weight ratio significantly, even if only for a short time (<1min)?  No.  The limit is the core properties, plus the above mentioned manipulations.  There aren't magnetic materials that can achieve this yet, at least common and affordable ones


