Modelling power transfer under saturation for 1:N current transformer in LTspice
A toroidal current transformer consisting of two half-toroids with air gaps, is clamped around an overhead 50 Hz AC power line carrying 50-300 A (i.e. a 1:N CT).  It is used for energy harvesting.
Is this a good circuit to use to simulate the saturation characteristics / energy transfer limitations of this transformer (the inductor L2 uses the John Chan model)?

From Simulating Non-linear Transformers in LTspice.
If yes:

how would I estimate the Chan inductor values Br and Hc?
how would I obtain the peripheral values Lpf & Lsf (primary/secondary leakage inductance)

This circuit produces tiny output even at low R4.  I am not sure whether it's because it doesn't work well for N=1/Ns=100, or my values are wrong, or both.  FYI, from these input values...

... I derived these values.  It's the Br, Hc, Lsf and Lpf that I'm unsure of calculating (especially with respect to air gap), but if you spot issues with other parameters, feel free to point those out:

If the above-mentioned circuit isn't suitable for 1:N CTs in this setup, what would be a better circuit?  FWIW, I have tried and failed to get the Chan transformer at the bottom of this page.

Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/720047/maximizing-power-transfer-from-50hz-ac-line-via-toroidal-current-transformer

If I understand your chart correctly, you have a 1 cm air gap. You should avoid an air gap as much as possible for a "classic" transformer. Intentional air gaps are primarily for coupled coils ("transformers") which store energy, rather than transfer power "synchronously".

Sorry I should have modified the air gap before posting. Yes this can be reduced to <0.5mm but can't be eliminated.  Air gap heavily influences Br and the leakage inductances, so I wanted a decent way of estimating them based on the available data. Also, I wasn't sure whether the circuit/chan model used is inaccurate for primary turns=1, hence the questions

Here is my way of solving the problem. With a gap of 0.5 mm, the transformer efficiency is low. The core is far from saturated.

